# iphone to android converter app without breaking it's features

Tags: android, xcode

I'm looking for a good converter that will export an iphone/xcode app to an android platform. I was wondering if there is any.

Comment: If it's with in objective C then you can port it to java class and tweak the code

Answer (score 0):

`Android` and `IOS` use completely different concepts of programming. I don't think cross-compiling will ever be possible.

If you want to run one Code on several platforms, you'd have to use one of the Multiplatform approaches like [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the sort exists. There is a doubtful rumor that android, because Swift is open source, could adopt some of Swift, in which case you could easily port your code. However, nothing currently exists to do so.